# Convert array of objects to a object of two arrays - tyepscript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a input array of objects

```
[
  { col1: 'col1value1', col2: 'col2value1', col3: col1value3},
  { col1: 'col1value2', col2: 'col2value2', col3: col1value2}
]
```

Now I want to convert this into a object two arrays like below

```
columns:["col1" , "col2","col3"],
data: ["col1value1","col2value1" , "col1value3"] ,
      ["col1value2","col2value2" , "col1value2"]
```

is there any good way or faster way . as I am trying to use 2 foreach loop on all the values and creating   columns and data array

Comment: You can use `Object.keys(yourList[0])`, assuming all the objects have the same keys.  Then you'll need to loop over the array to get the values (you can use `Object.values()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Object.keys()` method to get all the columns and use `Array.prototype.map` method to traverse the array and get the values using `Object.values()` method.

```js
const input = [
  { col1: 'col1value1', col2: 'col2value1', col3: 'col1value3' },
  { col1: 'col1value2', col2: 'col2value2', col3: 'col1value2' },
];

const columns = Object.keys(input[0]);
const data = input.map((x) => Object.values(x));
console.log(columns);
console.log(data);
```